# MobileFirst 8.0 App Authenticity - Custom message

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, mobilefirst-server

Enabling app authenticity and testing for a tampered case has never been easier.  In MFP 8.0 it is very simple to setup and test it.  Kudos to the development team.

Having said that when the app authenticity fails, the system shows a standard error message "A**n error was encountered while processing the request from the application**" with a title "**Error**" [Link to the image of the error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u6slG.png)

Question: Is there a way to customize this error message.  For example it would be nice to inform the customer say "**App has been tampered and access to MFP server has been denied.  Uninstall and reinstall the app from proper source**"

-A

Answer (score 0):

It is currently not possible to alter the authenticity check error message. You are encouraged though to submit requests for enhancements: https://mobilefirstplatform.ibmcloud.com/help/

Comment: The link above takes to a page where there is another link to submit an RFE [https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/rfe/execute?use_case=submitRfe], but that link leads to a "Content not found error page".  Not sure if the link is temporarily broken or needs fix.  Will check sometime later.